# Добавление несколько меток по адресам из Базы Данных

Tags: java, android

### Как добавить несколько меток на карту Google из Бд?

```
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_INFOEVENTDB, null, null, null, null, null, null);


    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {    //поиск по адресу
        int adresseventIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_ADRESS);
        List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(cursor.getString(adresseventIndex), 100);
        Address add = list.get(0);
        String locality = add.getLocality();
        Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        double lat = add.getLatitude();
        double lng = add.getLongitude();




        gotoLocation(lat, lng, DEFAULTZOOM);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: найдите, как добавить одну метку, и повторите для каждого адресса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {    //поиск по адресу
        int adresseventIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_ADRESS);
        List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(cursor.getString(adresseventIndex), 100);
        Address add = list.get(0);
        String locality = add.getLocality();
        Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        double lat = add.getLatitude();
        double lng = add.getLongitude();

        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(lat, lng));
        locationMarker = googleMap.addMarker(marker);

        gotoLocation(lat, lng, DEFAULTZOOM);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: все равно 1 маркер выводит((

Comment: значит у вас курсор один раз пробегается.

Comment: обновил ответ. добавьте в конец while (cursor.moveToNext());

Comment: Вы не подскажете как мне сделать добавление меток только в одном городе? Может как то установить границы? А то пишу адрес, он добавляет в другой город, где такой же адрес.

Comment: Не совсем понял.. Вы же по координатам добавляете

Comment: В поле вводится адрес, через геокод ставится метка по адресу, но одинаковых адресов в России много, поэтому метка может быть не в том городе

Comment: быть может тогда надо указывать город в поле?